# Get distinct string in lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, distinct

I am trying to get distinct port names as follows-

```
var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
var distincts = ports.Distinct(m=>m);
```

But `Distinct()` gives error "it is not a delegate type".

I am very new to lambda. Any help?

Comment: just remove m=>m?

Comment: @LeiYang, thanks. its working.

Comment: parameter of OrderBy is `Func<TSource,TKey>`, but of Distinct is `IEqualityComparer<T> `

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to get distinct string values. Following code should work:

```
var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
var distincts = ports.Distinct();
```